# Facebook Login 3.0 with LibGDX

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, libgdx

I want to make a game using LibGDX, but I do not know how to open new dialog for Facebook login. Could someone tell me how to do it or maybe upload an sample project. The Facebook SDK needs to use the Android native UI library, but LibGDX is not.

Comment: Have you tried going to the facebook dev page? All the info and examples are there.

Comment: if you managed to do the facebook login within libgdx would you mind sharing a mini project with us, e.g login part?

Answer (score 4):

You need to isolate all the Android-specific code in the Android portion of your libGDX application.  Generally, the way to solve this in libGDX applications is to define a new interface that exports the API your common (platform-independent) code needs, and then implement that interface in the different backends with platform-specific code.

So, create an interface like this:

```
public interface FacebookLogin {
   public boolean tryToLogIn();
}
```

Then in the desktop backend, create a dummy implementation that does nothing but return false, and on the Android side create an implementation that does what you need (you may need to use a `Handler` to get things to run on the right thread).  Then pass the implementations down from the initialization code in each backend.

Comment: do you have a sample project?

Comment: See https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements3TierProjectSetup

Comment: i followed the https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/IntegratingAndroidNativeUiElements3TierProjectSetup tutorial and i managed to have android native ui elements along the libgdx. I created that interface FacebookLogin created the facebook instance but the login window did not appear. I tried to do like this:

Comment: @Override public void FacebookLogin() { uiThread.post(new Runnable() { public void run() { loginToFacebook(); } }); }
loginToFacebook is doing the login like in the Facebook samples.

Comment: @Lunatikul Please ask a separate question with your specific problem.  Please also read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Comment: updated example from new wiki: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Interfacing-with-platform-specific-code